# how to got specific frame in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movieclip(MCa) on the Main timeline on frame1, inside this movieclip i have another movieclip(MCb) on frame1 of (MCa) timeline, inside (MCb) there are buttons and when i press a button i want to goandplay (frame2) of the Main timeline. so far i've managed to go to (frame2) of (MCa) using the following code:

```
 MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay("2");
```

but when i add this code :

```
MovieClip(this.parent.parent).gotoAndPlay("2");
```

i get an error,
please advice me on what is the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use `addEventListener` vs your `MCb`'s buttons that would attach main timeline functions to them. In this case you won't have troubles addressing either `MCa`, `MCb` or main timeline, as you'll be in the main timeline's context. Otherwise, check `MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(2)` if it would fit your purpose.

To add a listener, use the following in the context of main timeline:

```
MCa.MCb.TheButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goTo2);
public function goTo2(e:MouseEvent:):void {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

`TheButton` is the instance name of the button that you want to make main timeline advance to frame 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MovieClip(MovieClip(this.parent).parent).gotoAndPlay("2");
```

Comment: tried but still same result i get an error and the error says : cannot convert flash.display::Sprite to flash.display.MovieClip

Comment: Then you've to replace MovieClip with Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

```
MovieClip(this.parent.parent).gotoAndPlay("2");
```

Here you are going to a frame with a label name of "2".

Whereas if you use

```
MovieClip(this.parent.parent).gotoAndPlay(2);
```

This will go to frame number 2.

i.e. if you use quotation marks, gotoAndPlay is expecting a frame label.